# Fetch a particular list from table and fetch the remaining afterwards, using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, fetch

This is the complicated query I have ever thought about. I know this will be the one more silly questions.

I have an array of id's which has more than 100 id's inside it. I want to fetch everything from the database, but first the list that equals to id and afterwards I want the remaining.

My attempt:

PHP:

```
$arr = array(3,1,4);
sort($arr)
$implodedArr = implode(" || id = ", $arr);
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = implodedArr;
```

I don't think whatever I am doing is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The strategy first is to use the `IN` operator, rather than lots of concatenated `OR` statements - this should be faster. We can then use `UNION` to merge in the ones that don't appear in the first set.

I've marked the found set has having a virtual column of "important=1", for sorting purposes, but you can change this to something more meaningful if you like.

PHP:

```
$arr = array(3,1,4);
sort($arr)
$implodedArr = implode(",", $arr);
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT
    *, 1 AS important FROM tablename WHERE id IN ($implodedArray)
UNION
SELECT
    *, 0 AS important FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN ($implodedArray)
ORDER BY
    /* You can order by other fields after "important" if you wish */
    important DESC;
```